# Yii using database instead of cookies

Tags: php, database, validation, cookies, yii

Hello guys I am new in Yii framework and first of all what I am starting to do is creating user register/login system. I really want my system to be secure, but I found out that using cookies is not the safest method at all. So I have some suggestions that can be interesting, please remember that I am not professional PHP programer, so this suggestions can contain some bugs, but I think we will fix them.

As I understand when someone visits Yii website, first of all Yii tries to get the cookie and checks if it is already logged in. So why we can't use database instead of cookies? What I mean is that we can have this fields in database:

```
ip
remember_me
latest_visit
```

So, why we can't let Yii to check database instead of cookies? What I mean is that to let Yii check if guest ip == ip from db and remember_me == true, and latest_visit was not before 7 days. So instead of cookie validation using this method will be better. And after that let Yii to do whatever it does after cookie validation.

What we will achieve is remember me method for non cookie enabled browsers, avoiding cookie stealing and making user login system more secure since every data will be stored in the server side and on the client side will not be stored anything.

So how to do this? What do you think? how to make Yii do the task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IP addresses do not identify things reliably; there can be NAT (network address translation) at play so that multiple machines appear to come from the same address, not to mention DHCP leases expiring, and the possibility of different people using a single machine (kids using Dad's machine?) and so on.  So, with the information given, you'd have zero proof that the browser has even visited your site before.  Of course, some people use multiple browsers from a single machine (say Firefox, Chrome, Safari); cookies for one will probably not be available to the others.

What you are suggesting is woefully insecure.  Please don't try it for production use.

Comment: ok Thank you for your advice, it seems that I was wrong. Thank you for explaining the issues.